# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-jms

I am facing issue while starting my project.

**Environment:**

*Tomcat 6, Jdk_6.45,
**Alredy added**: com.ibm.mq.jar, com.ibm.mqjms.jar,*

**Context.xml**

```
<Context>
...
<Resource name="jms/sl.mqfactory" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
        factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory" description="JMS Queue Connection Factory"
        HOST="mqqs01.s.abc.co.uk" PORT="53162" CHAN="MQ.CLT.BLP.CHL.DEV"
        TRAN="1" CCS="819" QMGR="QS01" auth="Container" username="" password="" />

</Context>
```

Spring:

```
<bean id="jndiConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="${sl.mqfactory}" /> <!--from properties file -->
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory
```

Comment: What means classpath com.ibm.mq.jar, com.ibm.mqjms.jar?  where are these files located?

Comment: The problem is it can't find the class which means the jar it can't be found

Comment: Jar are in lib folder.

Comment: @StathisAndronikos, `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory` is in Jar

Comment: Can you tell me if the specific class is contained in more than 1 jar so that you have a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through [this link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/26108-problems-injecting-the-connectionfactory-and-queue-into-defaultmessagelistenercontain), I added **J2ee.jar** [without servlet package|folder in jar in my case(1.4.1) ]

And It's working now.

if you add j2ee jar with servlet folder tomcat will ignore it with `jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/..`

Actually MQQueueConnectionFactory needs **javax.resource-api**